# Multi-range slider using Ionic and React

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, slider

I'm trying to create a slider with a general time range and ability to select multi time ranges within.

So far, I was only able to create a simple slider. Like this:

```
<IonItem>
 <IonRange min={6} max={18} step={12} dualKnobs={true} color="primary" onIonChange={e => 
 setRangeValue(e.detail.value as any)}>
    <IonLabel slot="start">6</IonLabel>
    <IonLabel slot="end">18</IonLabel>
 </IonRange>
</IonItem>
```

Here's an image with I wish to develop:

[image]

Is there a way to do this with Ion Range? Or with react libraries? I wasn't really able to find anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find anything? I'm currently looking for something similar